# his error i get when I install and run spring tool suite. how can i fix it?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

This error I get when I install and run spring tool suite. how can I fix it?

Plug-in org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted was unable to load class

> org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard.

Comment: depending on the version of STS I would suggest to check the JDK you are running on. If that doesn't work, please provide more details here.

Comment: sir I am using the version sts 3.9.2 release and jdk 1.8

Comment: I think there is already a discussion about this going on here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/252 - so lets continue at GitHub and try to find a solution